# How do I define a basedir in Jade using only Prepros to compile templates?

Tags: html, pug, prepros

I'm using Jade without Node, I'm simply using the software Prepros to compile the templates to static HTML.

I want to include partials that are outside of the folder the Jade templates are in, like so:

`include /partials/foo.html`

However, using paths that begin with a `/` with `include` in Prepros gives the following error:

*the "basedir" option is required to use "include" with "absolute" paths*

Usually you could set the `basedir` using something like `app.locals.basedir = __dirname + '/views'`, but there's no way to do this with Prepros. Is there some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is security restriction imposed by jade language. I have added a workaround in Prepros Jade compiler to fix this issue, fix will be available from the next version of Prepros.

Answer (score 0):

You can just deleted `/` and it will works.

You also can add the path in the root folder and just call it like foot.html.